# How do I parse google search results in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

### My list keeps showing up empty

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keywords = ['"site:instagram.com" "@gmail.com" "gadgets"']

url = ('https://google.com/search?q='+''.join(keywords))

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

emails = soup.body.findAll(r"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+]" ,re.I)

print(emails)
```

### no error messages are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup seems overkill for this. You can accomplish this with simple `re.findall`

```py
import requests
import re

# search terms in a list
keywords = ["site:instagram.com", "@gmail.com", "gadgets"]

# join the list using the plus character
url = 'https://google.com/search?q={}'.format('+'.join(keywords))
print(url)

response = requests.get(url)

# \w means word
regex = r"[\w._-]+@[\w._-]+\.[\w._-]+"

emails = re.findall(regex, str(response.content))
print(emails)
```